# Distributed database use cases

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning, distributed-system, large-data, bigdata

At the moment i do have a mysql database, and the data iam collecting is 5 Terrabyte a year. I will save my data all the time, i dont think i want to delete something very early.
I ask myself if i should use a distributed database because my data will grow every year. And after 5 years i will have 25 Terrabyte without index. (just calculated the raw data i save every day)

i have 5 tables and the most queries are joins over multiple tables.
And i need to access mostly 1-2 columns over many rows at a specific timestamp.

Would a distributed database be a prefered database than only a single mysql database?

Paritioning will be difficult, because all my tables are really high connected.

I know it depends on the queries and on the database table design and i can also have a distributed mysql database. 
i just want to know when i should think about a distributed database.
Would this be a use case? or could mysql handle this large dataset?

EDIT:

- in average i will have 1500 clients writing data per second, they affect all tables.
- i just need the old dataset for analytics. Like machine learning and
  pattern matching.
- also a client should be able to see the historical data

Comment: Given your query load, you should look into partitioning the tables.  There might be other very reasonable solutions as well.

Comment: you mean only partitioning on one machine, no distributed partitioning?

Comment: It requires to know more about usage. Important is how many connections in average you have and how heavy queries they use. If they will still heavily use data from previous years or not, if queries are usually limited to one particular year, how quick responses are expected etc. Also which version of MySQL you have and configuration of server/ instance - CPUs/memory/if used only for mysql etc. May happen at some point you will need separate instance for every year and query them from main connection database using federated engine. But without detailed knowledge of load it is hard to say...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is about "distributed", but I see more serious questions that need answering first.

"Highly indexed 5TB" will slow to a crawl.  An index is a BTree.  To add a new row to an index means locating the block in that tree where the item belongs, then read-modify-write that block.  But...

- If the index is `AUTO_INCREMENT` or `TIMESTAMP` (or similar things), then the blocks being modified are 'always' at the 'end' of the BTree.  So virtually all of the reads and writes are cacheable.  That is, updating such an index is very low overhead.
- If the index is 'random', such as UUID, GUID, md5, etc, then the block to update is *rarely* found in cache.  That is, updating this one index for this one row is likely to cost a pair of IOPs.  Even with SSDs, you are likely to not keep up.  (Assuming you don't have several TB of RAM.)
- If the index is somewhere between sequential and random (say, some kind of "name"), then there might be thousands of "hot spots" in the BTree, and these might be cacheable.

Bottom line: If you cannot avoid random indexes, your project is doomed.

Next issue...  The queries.  If you need to scan 5TB for a `SELECT`, that *will* take time.  If this is a Data Warehouse type of application and you need to, say, summarize last month's data, then building and maintaining Summary Tables will be very important.  Furthermore, this can obviate the need for some of the indexes on the 'Fact' table, thereby possibly eliminating my concern about indexes.

"See the historical data" -- See individual rows?  Or just see summary info?  (Again, if it is like DW, one rarely needs to see old datapoints.)  If summarization will suffice, then most of the 25TB can be avoided.

Do you have a machine with 25TB online?  If not, that may force you to have multiple machines.  But then you will have the complexity of running queries across them.

5TB is estimated from INT = 4 bytes, etc?  If using InnoDB, you need to multiple by 2 to 3 to get the actual footprint.  Furthermore, if you need to modify a table in the future, such action probably needs to copy the table over, so that doubles the disk space needed.  Your 25TB becomes more like 100TB of storage.

`PARTITIONing` has very few valid use cases, so I don't want to discuss that until knowing more.

"Sharding" (splitting across machines) is possibly what you mean by "distributed".  With multiple tables, you need to think hard about how to split up the data so that `JOINs` will continue to work.

The 5TB is huge -- Do everything you can to shrink it -- Use smaller datatypes, normalize, etc.  But don't "over-normalize", you could end up with terrible performance.  (We need to see the queries!)

There are *many* directions to take a multi-TB db.  We really need more info about your tables and queries before we can be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

It's really impossible to provide a specific answer to such a wide question.

In general, I recommend only worrying about performance once you can prove that you have a problem; if you're worried, it's much better to set up a test rig, populate it with representative data, and see what happens.

"Can MySQL handle 5 - 25 TB of data?" Yes. No. Depends. If - as you say - you have no indexes, your queries may slow down a long time before you get to 5TB. If it's 5TB / year of highly indexable data it might be fine.

The most common solution to this question is to keep a "transactional" database for all the "regular" work, and a datawarehouse for reporting, using a regular Extract/Transform/Load job to move the data across, and archive it. The data warehouse typically has a schema optimized for querying, usually entirely unlike the original schema.

If you want to keep everything logically consistent, you might use [sharding](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/scalability.html) and clustering - a sort-a-kind-a out of the box feature of MySQL.

I would not, however, roll my own "distributed database" solution. It's much harder than you might think.